# PHP script takes too long and times out

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, payment-gateway

When I add the function below to my PHP page, it times out trying to execute the script. What's wrong with it?

```
include ('config.php');

function GenerateTransID() {    
    $unique_ref_length = 9;  
    $unique_ref_found = false;  
    $possible_chars = "23456789BCDFGHJKMNPQRSTVWXYZ";  
    while (!$unique_ref_found) {  
        $unique_ref = "";  
        $i = 0;  
        while ($i < $unique_ref_length) {  
            $char = substr($possible_chars, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible_chars)-1), 1);  
            $unique_ref .= $char;  
            $i++;  
        }

        $tmp_id = "TR-" . $unique_ref;
        $unique_ref = $tmp_id;
        $query = "SELECT `transactionID` FROM `payment` WHERE `transactionID`='$unique_ref'";  
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error().' '.$query); 

        if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0) {  
            $unique_ref_found = true;  

        }  

    }  
    return $unique_ref;         
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That function will only return if `mysql_num_rows($result) == 0`, which might not happen before the program times out.

Try adding a echo in that if to see if it is executed. If I were you I would take a look at generating GUIDs instead.

Comment: Yes, or put `return $unique_ref;` into `while` scope

Comment: He could do that as well - but if he never enters the crucial if, that won't matter...

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you, but if you put in that way function will return result and won't cause infinite loop

Comment: The way he has the `while` setup, it should stop as soon as he sets `$unique_ref_found` to true, which he does in the if. Moving the return into the if will only help if `mysql_num_rows()` ever returns `0`.

Comment: I wrote moving return into the outer `while`, not `if`

Comment: Then the function could return before he gets a unique ID... that's what the if is for. It would return the first ID.

Answer (score 0):

Change to the following:-

```
function GenerateTransID() {    
    $unique_ref_length = 9;  
    $unique_ref_found = false;  
    $possible_chars = "23456789BCDFGHJKMNPQRSTVWXYZ";
    while (!$unique_ref_found) {  
        $unique_ref = "";  
        for($i = 0; $i < $unique_ref_length; $i++) {  
            $char = substr($possible_chars, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible_chars)-1), 1);  
            $unique_ref .= $char;  
        }

        $tmp_id = "TR-" . $unique_ref;
        $unique_ref = $tmp_id;
        $query = "SELECT `transactionID` FROM `payment` WHERE `transactionID`='$unique_ref'";  
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error().' '.$query); 

        if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0)
        {
            $unique_ref_found = true;  
        }
    }
    return $unique_ref;
}
```

Made some code improvements. Other then that the function should work as expected. You have another issue that is not related to this code and most likely due to some other code or your database connection.

Comment: All You've done is change from a while to a for, that won't solve the problem either. While I do agree that a for would be better for him.

Comment: @fredrik execute the function and it will return a valid transaction ID, just be sure to comment out the unique ID db checking part

Comment: What is what he wan't help with fixing... he wan't all of it to work, not just all but probably one of the more important features - checking for duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

It may be SQL query. But you will never know until you will profile it. Check xdebug:

http://xdebug.org/